# Tehillim 60:13 / 108:13 - ‘the help of man is worthless’

Tags: tehilim-psalms

Shalom.

The JPS English translation of Tehillim 60:13 and 108:13 reads ‘Grant us your aid against the foe, for the help of man is worthless.’

Does this mean that it is a waste of time to ask one’s fellow man for help when one is suffering?

Many thanks.